# EntityFramework SaveChanges Moving EntityState From 'Added' to 'Detached'

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am writing a unit test which requires data to be set up in context before executing the method I am trying to test.

Calling `SaveChanges()` on my In-Memory DB context does not persist the data to memory. The state is modified from 'Added' to 'Detached', which is not supposed to happen according to the documentation.

Relevant Code:

```
private MyObject AddMyObject(MyObject myObjectToAdd, DateTimeOffset currentDate) {
            myObjectToAdd.CreatedDate = currentDate;
            // _db.Entry(myObjectToAdd).State is Detached
            _db.MyObjects.Add(myObjectToAdd);
            // _db.Entry(myObjectToAdd).State is Added
            _db.SaveChanges();
            // _db.Entry(myObjectToAdd).State is Detached and untracked -> Should be Unmodified and being tracked
            return myObjectToAdd;
        }
```

When I then go to query the in-memory database, the added object is not there.

Why is data not being persisted in this example?

I have tried setting the `Id` which is a Database Generated Identity column to `null`.

Second Attempt for clarity:

```
private MyObject AddMyObject(MyObject myObjectToAdd, DateTimeOffset currentDate) {
            myObjectToAdd.CreatedDate = currentDate;
            myObjectToAdd.ModifiedBy = "some String";
            myObjectToAdd.ModifiedDate = currentDate;
            // _db.Entry(cs).State is Detached
            MyObject cs = new MyObject () {
                Prop1 = myObjectToAdd.Prop1,
                Prop2 = myObjectToAdd.Prop2,
                ModifiedBy = myObjectToAdd.ModifiedBy,
                ModifiedDate = myObjectToAdd.ModifiedDate,
                CreatedDate = myObjectToAdd.CreatedDate,
                Prop3 = myObjectToAdd.Prop3
            };
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_db.Entry(cs).State);
            var insertedMyObject = _db.MyObjects.Add(cs).Entity;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_db.Entry(cs).State);
            // _db.Entry(cs).State is Added

            try
            {
              _db.SaveChanges();
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_db.Entry(cs).State);
            } catch (DbUpdateException u) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(u.Message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After Save");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_db.Entry(cs).State);
            // _db.Entry(cs).State is Detached -> Should be Unmodified and being tracked
            return insertedMyObject;
        }
```

Something weird is happening:

It only happens on the first save. Calling the method a second time results in one record in MyObjects. Calling the method a third time results in two records in MyObjects and so on.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when you are saving to the database?

Comment: We need more than 3 lines of code. Take a look at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Comment: @Train Added entities are inserted into the database and then become Unchanged when SaveChanges returns. 

This is the documentation I was referring to. I'm confused as to why it is not behaving like the documentation. Calling SaveChanges() changes the state from Added to Detached. I could provide more code, but this is the relevant code. 

I'm not sure what else to try, short of submitting a bug report to EntityFramework to see if its a bug or not.

Comment: @jdweng  I don't believe so... Vscode says a thread finished (exited), but I do not get any exception that I can see while debugging. Unless it is failing silently somehow and the exception is being caught within entity framework.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on feedback, but we need to know where `myObjectToAdd` is comming from. Is it from another dbContext instance? API call? How are you constructing it?

Comment: @Train I appreciate you responding so quickly. I updated my code for the sake of debugging to make it more clear. I am instantiating a new MyObject before inserting. In this case myObjectToAdd was created in another method, but it was also instantiated using the new MyObject() route and was not previously existing in the database. _db in this case is an in memory Entity Framework database object. MyObject has a property Id which is the Primary Key and it is database generated as Identity. I am not explicitly setting it, so it is defaulting to 0.

Comment: Great! Just one thing I forgot to mention, can you wrap the savechanges in a try catch with these 3 exceptions `DbEntityValidationException DbUpdateException and Execption`. Also look at the output window for erros right after save changes is called. Let me know if you see anything.

Comment: Just one more question just in case, is `myObjectToAdd` a Many to Many relationship?

Comment: @Train I added exception catching to my code at the top of the thread. There is no DbEntityValidationException in EF Core The output is Detached -> Added -> Detached -> After Save -> Detached. No errors that I can see anywhere. It's the weirdest thing. Also from what I've read, in memory ef core db's are not relational at all, so I don't know if that applies. In the actual sql server, it has just one relationship (one to many).

Comment: Hmmm let's start from square 1 then. Show us your connection string and how the connection to the DB is set up.

Comment: @Train thanks for bearing with me. See my updated code if you have a moment. I wonder if something is going on with the scoping. Can you think of any reason why calling a public method within the same class would mess with EF Core functionality?

Comment: When writing tests. The key to testing with this provider is the ability to tell the context to use the InMemory provider, and control the scope of the in-memory database. Typically you want a clean database for each test method with the `UseInMemoryDatabase()` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory Is it possible to set up an example with this issue? It's a little difficult for me to debug at the moment.